# Should we use Firebase or Google Compute Engine?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, server-side

Our clients will send two numbers to this server-side compute engine, and we want this server to notify all those clients who sent numbers that add up > 10.

Researching online it seems Google Compute Engine can do this but we’re not sure if it can send notifications.

- Should we use Firebase or Google Cloud Platform ?
- Any pre-existing
  APIs we can use here ?

This is our first time setting up something like this so we are confused how to go about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood you want a simple push notification mechanism.
Firebase is part of the GCP so when you decide to use Firebase, actually you are using a GCP project.

Consider taking a look at [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more#firebase-cloud-relationship) to understand their relationship better.

On the other hand, there is no more separate cloud messaging only for GCP according to [this](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging). Now your only option if you want to stay faithful to google platform for that matter is [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging)

Comment: thank you @kian. i ended up using firebase and it all worked out. thank you for the help here